What is すめばよし? What kind of nuance does it give?

有能ではあるが面倒ごとがとても嫌いな性格だ。面倒だけですめばよし、けれど義務が発生するとなると…

"He's very capable, but he has a personality where he hates things that are a pain in the ass."
But then what is the second part saying? "To finish them as 面倒 is good but then if an obligation occurs?"

You're almost there:

面倒だけですめばよし、けれど義務が発生するとなると…
It's okay if it's just (a matter of) "hassle", but if it (even) leads to obligations...

The sentence implies that he might say yes if it's a bothersome but one-time request, but if it involves (long-time) obligations, the chances of him saying yes are very slim.
～だけで済む means "can be resolved with just ～" or "just ～ is enough".

電池の交換だけで済む。
It can be done by just replacing the battery.
テストは簡単だから、1時間勉強するだけで済む。
The test is easy, so studying just for an hour will suffice.


I think this mainly comes down to the nuance of 済む itself. jisho.org has the definition "to merely result in something less severe than expected​". In your context, the meaning is something like "It would be good if that was as far as the problem went".
You should also look into the grammar point 〜ずに済む, because it uses 済む with a similar nuance.
